# How to get file name with dash

Tags: file, vba

I hope you are all well. Please pardon me if my question is a total noob one, but I can't google the solution.

I need to get part of the file's name and move it the file to specific folder (Category) respectively. Problem is, I will have multiple JPEG files with some specific format name, and are given to me by my boss' supplier.
The files contain picture of the car's spare part and named with following format

code - name - category - description

I would need to get Category, and the only clue I got is the two dashes that split the code, name and the category. The code, name, and description are totally random in length and content.

Example:

1099 - ball joint - suspension - the ball joint for Honda Civic, reusable for Honda Accord.JPEG

3275 - air filter - machine - air filter for Toyota Corolla, can also be used for Camry.JPEG

What i need is to get the "suspension" and "machine" and move each of the files to their respective folder. I have no idea how to split and get the data after two dashes.

Any respond would be much appreciated. Thank you. Have a great day.

Comment: I see three dashes, not two, in your examples.

Comment: `Split(filename,"-")` will give you an array of the dash-separated parts.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same method then [mehow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/mehow), as I've worked out the detail, I give here:

```
Function entDirExists(ByVal strDir)
'
  Dim fso
'
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  entDirExists = fso.FolderExists(strDir)
'
  Set fso = Nothing
End Function

'
'   i: counter
'   idxDir: index of the directory name in the split array
'
'   strFilename: current Filename
'   strSrcDir: source directory path
'   strDstDirPrefix: destination directory path prefix
'   strDstDir: destination directory for a category
'
'   xarr: split array of filename
'
Function entMoveFiles(ByVal strSrcDir)
'
  Dim i, idxDir
'
  Dim strFilename, strDstDirPrefix, strDstDir
  Dim xarr
'
  idxDir = 2
'
' strSrcDir = "D:\users\tmp"
'
  strDstDirPrefix = strSrcDir
'
' get the first image file:
'
  strFilename = Dir(strSrcDir & "\*.jpeg", vbNormal)
'
' loop over the source directory for images:
'
  i = 0
  Do While (strFilename <> "")
    '
    ' split filename:
    '
    xarr = Split(strFilename, "-")
    '
    ' get the destination directory full path like prefix\catetory:
    '
    strDstDir = xarr(idxDir)
    strDstDir = strDstDirPrefix & "\" & Trim(strDstDir)
    '
    ' create the destination directory if nonexistent:
    '
    If (Not entDirExists(strDstDir)) Then
      MkDir strDstDir
    End If
    '
    ' move the current file: [source path] as [destination path]
    '
    Name strSrcDir & "\" & strFilename As strDstDir & "\" & strFilename
    '
    ' get next file:
    '
    strFilename = Dir()
    i = i + 1
  Loop
'
  entMoveFiles = i
'
End Function
```

To handle a directory name "D:\myjpegs", one uses this:

```
entMoveFiles "D:\myjpegs"
```

It will create subdirectories for each category, such as suspension, machine under D:\myjpegs if they don't already exist.